Build Python wheel for ARM macOS on Linux
I would like to build a python wheel package for ARM macOS but I have only Linux server (Gitlab CI). Is it possible to build wheel for ARM Mac on Linux server? If so how? I did not find much relevant information using Google.

You could use Docker's qemu support to run an arm64 Python container: docker --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.12 and build the wheel in the container.

@AKX The OP asked for Mac, not Linux.

Oohp, sorry, I misread somehow.

cibuildwheel can be used to build wheels for multiple platforms

So I am just trying the cibuildwheel but I cannot get it to work. I tried running it inside python:3.12.2-bookworm container but it tries to install python by itself and errors at non-existing pkgutil. Then I tried quay.io/pypa/manylinux2014_x86_64, manually installed python but errored on installing cibuildwheel :(

@Mo711 Could cibuildwheel be run under one platform (Linux/amd64) and build wheels for a completely different platform (macOS/arm64)?
